# How to run an apk file on a web browser making the apk know that it is on a real device and not on a emulator

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, apk, emulation

I made an android app, which uses firebase phone auth. As i mentioned in the title is it possible to run an apk on a emulator without allowing firebase phone auth to know that it is on an emulator as firebase phone auth dosent work on emulators

My emulator is appetize.io , a web based phone emulator

Comment: Related: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#test-with-fictional-phone-numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you use firebase-auth:20.0.0 or later (launched 2 days ago), or the Firebase BoM 26.0.0 or later then you should be able to use the reCAPTCHA flow of Android Phone Auth, which will work on emulators. Give that a shot and let me know how it goes :)

Comment: Thank you from my heart for giving me this info. Can you also please further help me in integrating it into into my existing app. Lets continue this on chat

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, unless you have some very special emulator that can somehow operate as if it has a working phone number that can receive SMS messages.  Typical emulators do not have this capability - only real devices can send and receive SMS that would be used to validate its working phone number.

Comment: But my need is to run an apk with firebase phone auth on web as i cant build a web app from scratch

Comment: APK only run on Android natively.  They can't be used for web apps.